# Can an element of the closure of the span of an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space be represented by a Fourier series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-series

A problem I'm struggling with is this: If $(e_k)$ is an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space $H$, and we denote $M=\operatorname{span}(e_k)$, then for all $x\in \bar M$ we have that $x$ can be represented as 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$$
Now as $x\in \bar M \implies x\in H$ quite obviously it follows that the above series converges. However, I am struggling to prove that this series converges to $x$. I'm pretty sure I need to use the fact that $x$ is in the closure of $M$ but I'm not quite sure how to bring this in. Any hints as to how to start the proof would be appreciated.

PROGRESS:
If we let $x'$ denote the limit of the series I'm able to show using Daniel's hint that $\langle x',e_j\rangle=\langle x,e_j\rangle \ \  \forall j\in \mathbb{N}$. As this is true for every $j$ I'd like to be able to conclude that $x'=x$, but I'm not really sure if I have any justification for such a conclusion.

Comment: By the continuity and sesquilinearity of the inner product, $$\Biggl\langle \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \alpha_k e_k, y\Biggr\rangle = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \alpha_k \langle e_k,y\rangle$$ when $\sum \alpha_k e_k$ is a convergent series.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for the hint but I can't see how to bring in the fact that $x\in \bar M$ using it. Do I not need to use it?

Comment: Letting $y = e_m$, you can determine the coefficients in $x = \sum \alpha_k e_k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I realised that I did not actually state my question correctly,  so please restate your hint if you'd like. Sorry my brain is not at its best tonight it seems.

Comment: No worries, that's a semi-permanent state for most of us. Let $x' = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \langle x, e_k\rangle e_k$. Note that $x- x' \in M^{\perp}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you. If you'd like to check my progress to see whether  I'm using your hints as intended I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in \overline{M}$, then, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $m = \sum_{k=1}^{N}\alpha_k e_k$ such that $\|x-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\alpha_ke_k\| < \epsilon$. For every $n \ge N$, 
$$
      \left(x-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k\right)\perp \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k-m\right)
$$
because the difference on the left is orthogonal to $e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n$, and because the vector on the right is a linear combination of such $e_k$. Therefore, by the Pythagorean Theorem,
\begin{align}
     \epsilon^2 > \|x-m\|^2
   & =\|x-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k\|^2+\|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k-m\|^2 \\
   & \ge \|x-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k\|^2,\;\;\; n \ge N.
\end{align}
By the definition of vector limit, $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$, because, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $\|x-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k\| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \ge N$.

Conversely, if $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$, then $x \in \overline{M}$ because the partial sums are in $M$.